# How to dynamic adding rows into asp.net table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add rows in a table from server-side?

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
      Session["table"] = TableId;
  }
  else
  {
      TableId = (Table)Session["table"];
  }

protected void btnAddinRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      num_row = (TableId.Rows).Count;

      TableRow r = new TableRow();
      TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
      TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
      TextBox t = new TextBox();

      t.ID = "textID" + num_row;
      t.EnableViewState = true;

      r.ID = "newRow" + num_row;
      c1.ID = "newC1" + num_row;
      c2.ID = "newC2" + num_row;

      c1.Text = "New Cell - " + num_row;
      c2.Controls.Add(t);

      r.Cells.Add(c1);
      r.Cells.Add(c2);

      TableId.Rows.Add(r);
      Session["table"] = TableId;
}
```

in debug I found out the number in the "TableID", but the rows are not drawn.

Have you got an idea about this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing with Dynamic Controls...  Incase you are creating each of the row in the Table Dynamically... You need to create it (with the same name) on every page cycle.. Whether it is postback or not...

In simple terms, if you are creating something that is not in the .aspx (Tag) page, in your code... Do it on every postback...

In your code, you are retrieving the Table from the Session, but you are not adding it again to the form... The below line does that.

```
            this.form1.Controls.Add(TableId);
```

Here is a working code, for your question... hope this helps.  Let me know, if you have any questions... Also you may try DataGrid with object Datasource... That will help you to retain the data on postback, without writing it to DB.

```
    Table TableId = new Table();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            TableId.ID = "MyTable";
        }
        else
        {
            TableId = (Table)Session["table"];
            this.form1.Controls.Add(TableId);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["table"] = TableId; 
    }


    protected void btnAddinRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num_row = (TableId.Rows).Count;

        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
        TextBox t = new TextBox();

        t.ID = "textID" + num_row;
        t.EnableViewState = true;

        r.ID = "newRow" + num_row;
        c1.ID = "newC1" + num_row;
        c2.ID = "newC2" + num_row;

        c1.Text = "New Cell - " + num_row;
        c2.Controls.Add(t);

        r.Cells.Add(c1);
        r.Cells.Add(c2);

        TableId.Rows.Add(r);
        Session["table"] = TableId;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
When I add controls to the form I get an exception "two control with same ID founds", I think I will try with a gridview. 
When I comment this: this.form1.Controls.Add(TableId);  the error not fire but add row doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: I think, you would have created the Table in design mode (aspx tag page) too... For the above code to work, you need not have to create the table in aspx page.

Comment: However I work in aspx. as you recommanded I'm try to use gridview, but I'm not familiar with this component. There is somme where an example using session with objecdatasource? sommething seems what I need. THank you again The King.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, using session to store existing table data. I have been stuck at this point for two days and everytime when I tried to add row into table and use request.form to retrieve existing data, the data will be erased since the Form is in master page. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering why would you use a table and not the `GridView` control that has so much powerful and you could accomplish this easily ??

A GridView can be hooked up with a `DataTable` as it's own `DataSource`, so, if you need to create a new row, all you need to do is create a new `DataRow` into the `DataTable` and bind it again.

You can use this using javascript (Ajax call) or in code-behind.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["myData"];
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dt);

myGridView.DataSource = dt;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

you don't need to worry about ID's as they will alwways be unique, and on save for example, you can easily loop through all rows and do what you need per row, like

```
public void SaveData()
{
    myBusinessObjectCollection = new myBusinessObjectCollection();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in myGridView.Rows)
    {
        myBusinessObjectCollection.Add(
            new myBusinessObject
            {
                C1 = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtNewC1")).Text,
                C2 = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtNewC2")).Text
            });
    }

    myBusinessObjectCollection.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this table is that to obtain data temporarily, I do not need stored data, it is only for reading. But I need these temporary data in server-side for treatments.

Comment: did you ever ear about Cookies? or hidden inputs to hold data temporarily ?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET controls are recreated each postback, so saving link on table in session doesn't make sense.

Store in session(or viewstate) some structure which **describes** your table (DataTable or collection of strongly typed objects), add rows in this structure on click button event and rebind table using this structure on OnPreRender event.

Comment: thank you, how to rendering the table? maybe could it work with the table stored on session. I see the number row in the object table but there are not drawn.

- I don't need to bind data in the table. It's only for insert data not read.