# Returning a random row from sql database and displaying in a html table using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Im new to using ASP.NET and would like to know how I can select a random row from a sql database and then display the fields in a html table on a separate page. It is intended that the user can press on button which will retrieve a random movie from the database and then display the movie details in a html table on a new page. I am not sure how to go about this and have been trying to use labels to display the data. Here is a sample of the code so far:

```
    private SqlConnection conn;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ConnectionStringSettings connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["MovieAppConnectionString1"];
            conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString);
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string queryString = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Movie ORDER BY NEWID()";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Image2.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                    Label1.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                    Desc.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                    Direc.Text = reader[5].ToString();
                    Strs.Text = reader[7].ToString();
                    Rtime.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                    ImdbRt.Text = reader[8].ToString();
                }
            }
       }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        Server.Transfer("MovieSelected.aspx");
```

Comment: I assume you are using SQL Server since you are using the NEWID() function?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?  Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Hi, yes im using SQL Server r2 2008

Comment: I've done something similar to this with PHP but not ASP.  It looks like you have the first part done as far the the query goes.  You will need to create an ASP function to build your html table and populate it with the database values retrieved from the select statement.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff My main problem is I dont know how to display the data I retrieved from the Sql query. I have a html table made in a separate page where I want to display the details of a movie from my database. I have labels in the table rows and Im not sure how I use these and stringbuilder to populate the table.

Comment: Thanks @N1tr0 I have a table created in a separate page. My main problem is how I go about populating the table?

Comment: Can you provide the code to your HTML page?  That is where the 'magic' happens. :-)

Comment: From my poking around, ASP.NET is quite a bit different from PHP when it comes to building dynamic tables.  I find PHP easier to understand.  Anyway, check out these links.  They might give you some insight:  

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169373/Dynamic-Table-in-Asp-Net-using-C

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003912/how-to-dynamic-adding-rows-into-asp-net-table

Comment: You can display the info as dynamic label array (using placeholder), or a simple gridview. I can help you in both cases just pick one.

Comment: Hi @BrOSs If you could help me with the dynamic label array that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sql server query from :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Movie ORDER BY NEWID()
```

to

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Movie ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Why would you change a SQL Server query to invalid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx.cs file:

```
int iLength = 0; 
int index = 0;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = SqlComm.SqlDataTable("SELECT * FROM Movie");

object obj = new object();
obj = SqlComm.SqlReturn("SELECT COUNT (yourTargetColumn) FROM yourTable");

if (obj != null)                    
     iLength = Convert.ToInt32(obj); 

string[] stringArray = new string[iLength];
for (index = 0; index < iLength; index++) 
{
     stringArray[index] = (string)dt.Rows[index]["yourTargetColumn"];                   
}
foreach (string strArray in stringArray)
{    
     Label yourLabel = new Label();
     PH.Controls.Add(yourLabel);
}
```

In your .aspx file:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PH" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Add a class to your App_Code folder named "SqlComm.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class SqlComm
{
   static string DatabaseConnectionString = "your connection string";

   public static object SqlReturn(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);                  
            object result = (object)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return result;           

        }
    }

   public static DataTable SqlDataTable(string sql)
   {
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
       {
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
           cmd.Connection.Open();
           DataTable TempTable = new DataTable();
           TempTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
           return TempTable;
       }
}
```

---

Note: Do not forget to add the `using System.Data.SqlClient` to your code. Also, you just have to customize the `SELECT` command in order to get the data you want.