# How to build a dynamic order form, which i can duplicate it by pressing a button

Tags: asp.net

I would like to build an order window in asp.net which contain some Labels, Text boxes and a button
The button will be called "Add more item" which by pressing on it, the Labels and Text boxes will be duplicate under the old ones. in that way i can control how many products i want to add.

**Questions:**
1. is this possible and how?
2. is there any other appropriate way?

Comment: This might give you some ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003912/how-to-dynamic-adding-rows-into-asp-net-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions: 1. is this possible and how?

Answer. Yes it is possible and here how can you do it.

1. Start with 1 label , 1 text box and 2 buttons and 2 panel as

   ```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Item1"></asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </asp:Panel>
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add more Item" onclick="Button1_Click" />
       <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Submit" />
   </asp:Panel>
   ```

The back end code will be

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
           Session["cnt"]= null;
      }
      if (Session["cnt"]!=null)
      {
           int cnt = (int)Session["cnt"];//get how many items are already there and add them to page
           for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
           {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "tb" + i.ToString();
                Label lb = new Label();
                lb.ID = "lb" + i.ToString();
                lb.Text = "item " + (i + 2).ToString();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
           }

      }


 }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int cnt = 0;
     if (Session["cnt"] != null)
     {
          cnt = (int)Session["cnt"];
     }
     cnt++;
     TextBox tb = new TextBox();
     tb.ID = "tb" + cnt.ToString();
     Label lb = new Label();
     lb.ID = "lb" + cnt.ToString();
     lb.Text = "item " + (cnt + 2).ToString();
     Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
     Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

     Session["cnt"] = cnt;
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int cnt = 0;
     if (Session["cnt"] != null)
     {
          cnt = (int)Session["cnt"];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
     {
          TextBox tb = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("tb" + i.ToString());
          Label lb = (Label)Panel1.FindControl("lb" + i.ToString());
          if (tb!=null&&lb!=null)
          {
               Response.Write(lb.Text + " - " + tb.Text + "<br/>");
          }
     }
}
```

question 2. is there any other appropriate way?
Answer: It depends upon the context. You can do this same thing using javascript which will save the roundtrip to server and will be faster.